# $(1+x)^n > \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$ when $1≤n$ and $0<x$ using newton binom

Tags: calculus

$(1+x)^n > \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$ when $ 1\leq n$ using newton binom

I don't know how to continue from here

$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}(1)^{k}x^k=?$$

Comment: Note that when $x$ is close to $1$, the LHS is nearly $0$ whereas the RHS is about $n(n-1)/2 \gg 0$. Thus this inequality fails, in particular, near $x=1$. Are there any conditions on $x$?

Comment: I edited the equation

Comment: Since all  terms of the sum are positive it's greater than its third summand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\geq 0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}x^k = {{n}\choose{0}} + {{n}\choose{1}}x+ {{n}\choose{2}}x^2+\ldots+{{n}\choose{n-1}}x^{n-1}+{{n}\choose{n}}x^n.$$
Since all the terms are positives, then
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}x^k > {{n}\choose{2}}x^2 =\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}x^2=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)!}{2(n-2)!}x^2=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$$

Comment: Im so sorry, I had a typo. I edited the equation

Comment: I edited my answer, but the inequality is not still true

Comment: what about when x > 0

Comment: Now it is. In fact, it is also valid for $x=0$

Comment: I really appreciate your help thank you